# Should I tag my puzzle with 'chess' if it requires a 'chessboard' and not a 'checkerboard'?

Tags: discussion, tags

About two years ago, I asked [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31620/18023) question. The solution requires a knowledge of the algebraic notation of chess positions, but doesn't require one to know how to play chess. Hence, I had [tagged the question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31620/who-stole-the-sorcerers-stone#comment95164_31620) with the `chessboard` tag. Now it seems that the tag has been deleted, and has been replaced with `checkerboard`, as I can't seem to find any other questions with that tag.

I tried editing it back to `chessboard`, but no changes were made.

I do believe that most of the questions tagged `chessboard` only require a board with a checkerboard pattern, but in my case, the `checkerboard` tag doesn't exactly fit, and the puzzle specifically requires a chessboard. Should I instead tag it with `chess` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were unable to edit [chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chessboard) back in because it became a synonym of [checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkerboard) a while back.

As for your actual question, I'd argue chess notations are specific to the actual game of chess more than they are to the board itself (e.g. it appears that [checkers uses a different notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts#Notation)), so therefore [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) is probably better than [checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkerboard).