# A checkerboard and eight queens

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should we use for questions about

> **A checkerboard and eight queens** ?

[chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) or [checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkerboard)?

EDIT: What does [this](http://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/should-i-tag-my-puzzle-with-chess-if-it-requires-a-chessboard-and-not-a-che) mean? Should I just use [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)?

Comment: Why not both? ;)

Comment: Use both! :D --

Comment: Answer it. Post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using both tags.

(Per Omega Krypton and Riddler's suggestions.)

There is a tag limit, but only up to 5 tags, so if a tag is relevant (and both are) put it in!

Comment: I made an edit to the question.

Comment: There **is** a hard limit of five (5) tags per question.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I would keep my answer the same. The linked case seems a little different, since in that question there was a difference between the chessboard and the checkerboard - the chess board _notation_, in particular, was needed for the problem. In this case, we need no notation, just a board that looks identical to a checkerboard.